# How to write pytest tests for a FastAPI route involving dependency injection with Pydantic models using Annotated and Depends?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, pytest, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to use pytest in order to test a simple API created in python with FastApi.
I am running into two issues:

- **Main issue:** if the function declares the input parameter with `Annotated` and `Depends`, I am unable to run the tests with `pytest`. The route responds with a 422 *Unprocessable Entity* status code.
- **Side issue:** I keep getting a deprecation warning when I create the test client:

```
> DeprecationWarning: The 'app' shortcut is now deprecated. Use the explicit style 'transport=ASGITransport(app=...)' instead.
```

Please let me know how to solve these two issues. I read about [dependency override](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/) but I am not sure if that is mandatory or how I could create multiple test cases for my app by varying the input in that approach (e.g.: test for different people in case my API should return different outputs for each).

In order to reproduce this error, I created a simple api in `Python 3.10.13`. This API has two routes with POST methods, one of which declares the input argument as a Pydantic Model of class `Person` directly (I can test this route, with a Deprecation warning), whileas the other one is using `Annotated[Person, Depends()]` (I do not know how to test this route, the test fails):

Here is the main.py file for my simple api:

```
# simple_api/main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Annotated

# Define a simple Pydantic v2 model to validate the post request
class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int = Field(..., ge=18, le = 130)

# Load app
app = FastAPI()

# I can test this route:
@app.post("/post_no_dependency")
def post_example_no_dependency(person: Person):
    return {
        "message": f"Hello {person.name}, your age is {person.age}",
        "method": "no dependency"
        }

# But I am not sure how to test this route:
@app.post("/post_with_dependency")
def post_example_with_dependency(
    person: Annotated[Person, Depends()]
    ):
    return {
        "message": f"Hello {person.name}, your age is {person.age}",
        "method":"with dependency"
        }
```

Here is the test file for my simple api:

```
# /simple_api/test_simple_api.py
import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient

from main import app

@pytest.fixture
async def async_client():
  """Fixture to create a FastAPI test client."""
  async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as async_test_client:
      yield async_test_client

# This test works
@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_post_example_no_dependency(async_client: AsyncClient):
    data = {"name": "john doe",
            "age": 32}
    response = await async_client.post("/post_no_dependency",
                                       json = data)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json()["method"] == "no dependency"

# This test fails because the status code is 422, not 200.
@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_post_example_with_dependency(async_client: AsyncClient):
    data = {"name": "john doe",
            "age": 32}
    response = await async_client.post("/post_with_dependency",
                                       json = data)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json()["method"] == "with dependency"
```

Here is what happens when I run pytest in a bash terminal (I am using a github codespace):

```
(simple_venv) @mikeliux ➜ /workspaces/simple_api $ pytest test_simple_api.py
==================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.13, pytest-8.1.1, pluggy-1.4.0
rootdir: /workspaces/simple_api
plugins: anyio-4.3.0
collected 4 items                                                                                                                                           

test_simple_api.py .F.F                                                                                                                               [100%]

========================================================================= FAILURES ==========================================================================
________________________________________________________ test_post_example_with_dependency[asyncio] _________________________________________________________

async_client = <httpx.AsyncClient object at 0x7f0e0cd893f0>

    @pytest.mark.anyio
    async def test_post_example_with_dependency(async_client: AsyncClient):
        data = {"name": "john doe",
                "age": 32}
        response = await async_client.post("/post_with_dependency",
                                           json = data)
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 422 == 200
E        +  where 422 = <Response [422 Unprocessable Entity]>.status_code

test_simple_api.py:30: AssertionError
__________________________________________________________ test_post_example_with_dependency[trio] __________________________________________________________

async_client = <httpx.AsyncClient object at 0x7f0e0c436770>

    @pytest.mark.anyio
    async def test_post_example_with_dependency(async_client: AsyncClient):
        data = {"name": "john doe",
                "age": 32}
        response = await async_client.post("/post_with_dependency",
                                           json = data)
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 422 == 200
E        +  where 422 = <Response [422 Unprocessable Entity]>.status_code

test_simple_api.py:30: AssertionError
===================================================================== warnings summary ======================================================================
test_simple_api.py::test_post_example_no_dependency[asyncio]
test_simple_api.py::test_post_example_with_dependency[asyncio]
test_simple_api.py::test_post_example_no_dependency[trio]
test_simple_api.py::test_post_example_with_dependency[trio]
  /workspaces/simple_api/simple_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:1426: DeprecationWarning: The 'app' shortcut is now deprecated. Use the explicit style 'transport=ASGITransport(app=...)' instead.
    warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
================================================================== short test summary info ==================================================================
FAILED test_simple_api.py::test_post_example_with_dependency[asyncio] - assert 422 == 200
FAILED test_simple_api.py::test_post_example_with_dependency[trio] - assert 422 == 200
========================================================== 2 failed, 2 passed, 4 warnings in 0.77s ==========================================================
```

Also, you can check the installed packages here:

```
(simple_venv) @mikeliux ➜ /workspaces/simple_api $ pip freeze
annotated-types==0.6.0
anyio==4.3.0
attrs==23.2.0
certifi==2024.2.2
click==8.1.7
dnspython==2.6.1
email_validator==2.1.1
exceptiongroup==1.2.0
fastapi==0.110.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httptools==0.6.1
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.6
iniconfig==2.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
orjson==3.10.0
outcome==1.3.0.post0
packaging==24.0
pluggy==1.4.0
pydantic==2.6.4
pydantic-extra-types==2.6.0
pydantic-settings==2.2.1
pydantic_core==2.16.3
pytest==8.1.1
python-dotenv==1.0.1
python-multipart==0.0.9
PyYAML==6.0.1
sniffio==1.3.1
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
starlette==0.36.3
tomli==2.0.1
trio==0.25.0
typing_extensions==4.10.0
ujson==5.9.0
uvicorn==0.29.0
uvloop==0.19.0
watchfiles==0.21.0
websockets==12.0
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It might be helpful to know what the full response body is (it will typically detail what fields were missing, etc).  Also, I'm pretty suspicious of your declaration of that request handler. Are you sure you can apply that annotation to a pydantic model class? Also, what is the meaning of calling `Depends` with no input? I could find no information about that - every usage I've seen provides a callable as a parameter to `Depends()`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the **Side issue** (`DeprecationWarning`) by making these changes in the test file:

```
# /simple_api/test_simple_api.py
import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient, ASGITransport # additional import

from main import app

@pytest.fixture
async def async_client():
  """Fixture to create a FastAPI test client."""
  # instead of app = app, use this to avoid the DeprecationWarning:
  async with AsyncClient(transport=ASGITransport(app=app), base_url="http://test") as async_test_client:
      yield async_test_client
```

Still, the **Main issue** remains unsolved. Here is the updated result:

```
(simple_venv) @mikeliux ➜ /workspaces/simple_api $ pytest test_simple_api.py
==================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.13, pytest-8.1.1, pluggy-1.4.0
rootdir: /workspaces/simple_api
plugins: anyio-4.3.0
collected 4 items                                                                                                                                           

test_simple_api.py .F.F                                                                                                                               [100%]

========================================================================= FAILURES ==========================================================================
________________________________________________________ test_post_example_with_dependency[asyncio] _________________________________________________________

async_client = <httpx.AsyncClient object at 0x7f837f36d330>

    @pytest.mark.anyio
    async def test_post_example_with_dependency(async_client: AsyncClient):
        data = {"name": "john doe",
                "age": 32}
        response = await async_client.post("/post_with_dependency",
                                           json = data)
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 422 == 200
E        +  where 422 = <Response [422 Unprocessable Entity]>.status_code

test_simple_api.py:31: AssertionError
__________________________________________________________ test_post_example_with_dependency[trio] __________________________________________________________

async_client = <httpx.AsyncClient object at 0x7f837f3e6500>

    @pytest.mark.anyio
    async def test_post_example_with_dependency(async_client: AsyncClient):
        data = {"name": "john doe",
                "age": 32}
        response = await async_client.post("/post_with_dependency",
                                           json = data)
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 422 == 200
E        +  where 422 = <Response [422 Unprocessable Entity]>.status_code

test_simple_api.py:31: AssertionError
================================================================== short test summary info ==================================================================
FAILED test_simple_api.py::test_post_example_with_dependency[asyncio] - assert 422 == 200
FAILED test_simple_api.py::test_post_example_with_dependency[trio] - assert 422 == 200
================================================================ 2 failed, 2 passed in 0.78s ================================================================
```